# Turn off Caps lock when Escape is pressed

Tags: keyboard, xkb, kubuntu

Is there any way to disable <kbd>CapsLock</kbd> whenever <kbd>Esc</kbd> is pressed. Yes, I use VIM! I actually have an alternative all-caps keyboard layout on <kbd>Ctrl-6</kbd> but I find it cumbersome and would prefer to just have the OS disable CapsLock whenever <kbd>Esc</kbd> is pressed. Also, I often SSH into other servers for a few hours so I'm on a stock VIM there.

Note that I happen to already have swapped the <kbd>CapsLock</kbd> and <kbd>Esc</kbd> keys. However, when the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key is pressed (which happens to be labeled `CapsLock` on the keyboard and is next to <kbd>A</kbd>), I need it to perform both `Escape` and `Disable-CapsLock-If-It-Is-Enabled`.

This is on Kubuntu 12.10. Thanks.

Comment: You need to add that functionality only for `vim`, or the complete desktop?

Comment: I would like it to be a desktop feature.

Answer (score 8):

In X11 (on console I don't know) you can do it by redefining the behaviour of the Escape key.
I looked at the "shift(break_caps)" definition to see how it works, and adapted it.

Look at [this answer on xkb](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65507/use-setxkbmap-to-swap-the-left-shift-and-left-control/65600#65600) for more details on how/where to put the locally modified files and load them.

And for doing what you want, you need in the local symbols file (eg: `~/.xkb/symbols/mysymbols`) a section like this:

```
partial modifier_keys
xkb_symbols "esc_breaks_caps" {
    key <ESC> {
        type = "ALPHABETIC",
        actions [Group1] = [
            SetMods(modifiers=none),
            SetMods(modifiers=Lock,clearLocks)
        ]
    };
};
```

and in the local keymap file (eg: `~/.xkb/keymap/mykbd`; you can create it with `setxkbmap -print > ~/.xkb/keymap/mykbd` ) change the `xkb_symbols` line to add `+mysymbols(esc_breaks_caps)`.

You can now load it with: `xkbcomp -I$HOME/.xkb ~/.xkb/keymap/mykbd $DISPLAY`
and pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd> will remove the CapsLock state (actually, the effect happens on the *release* of Esc; I think that only *modifiers* keys have immediate effect; others the effect is after their release.)

Oh, if you want to also swap Escape and CapsLock keys; then use this instead (and you put "+mysymbols(esc_swap_and_breaks_caps)" in your mykbd file):

```
partial modifier_keys
xkb_symbols "esc_swap_and_breaks_caps" {
    replace key <CAPS> {
        type = "ALPHABETIC",
        symbols = [ Escape, Escape ],
        actions [Group1] = [
            SetMods(modifiers=none),
            SetMods(modifiers=Lock,clearLocks)
        ]
    };
    replace key <ESC> { [ CapsLock, CapsLock ] };
};
```

note the physical keys are `<CAPS>` and `<ESC>`; `<CAPS>` (key engraved <kbd>CapsLock</kbd> in your keyboard) send Escape and `<ESC>` (key engraved <kbd>Esc</kbd>) sends CapsLock, whith `<CAPS>` (sending Escape) also unsetting capslock state

Answer (score 0):

Add these lines to `~/.Xmodmap` :

```
clear lock
keycode 0x42 = Escape
```

Then, type the command:

```
xmodmap ~/.Xmodmap
```

Your <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> key is now remapped to the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key.

[Reference url](http://wilt.isaac.su/articles/how-to-remap-your-capslock-key-to-esc-key-in-ubuntu-linux).

---

Also go through [this nice article about Mapping CapsLock to Escape in Ubuntu](http://jasonwryan.com/blog/2010/02/21/capslock/), which seems to be a unix.se user :)

Comment: Thank you. I happen to already have swapped CapsLock and Esc. However, when the Esc key is pressed (which happens to be labeled CapsLock on the keyboard and is next to A), I need it to perform _both_ Escape _and_ Disable-CapsLock-If-It-Is-Enabled. I will edit the question to clarify. Thanks.

Comment: I thought you needed the other-way round. Somewhat confused here. What happens on pressing `Esc` and `Capslocks` after these changes ?

Comment: Currently: when pressing the `ESC` key the `CapsLock` function toggles, and when pressing the `CapsLock` key the `ESC` command is sent (i.e. the `ESC` key is remapped to `CapsLock` and the `CapsLock` key is remapped to `ESC`). My goal with this question is to have pressing the `CapsLock` key perform _both_ the `ESC` function (which it currently does) _and_ turn off the `CapsLock` function if and only if the `CapsLock` function is enabled (i.e. not toggle the `CapsLock` function, but rather disable it if `CapsLock` is enabled).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this answers your question, but to map the <kbd>Esc</kbd> function to the <kbd>CapsLock</kbd> key, you can use this:

```
setxkbmap -option "caps:escape"
```