# Disable Caps Lock when a modifier key is pressed, with XKB

Tags: xkb, capslock

I would like all modifier keys -- except Shift -- to disable Caps Lock.  Since, I would like to swap some modifiers as well, I am trying to achieve both goals at the same time (I wouldn't know how to do otherwise).  After having read [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/65641/8785), I have tried the following code in my custom layout, but it doesn't work:

```
key <LCTL> {  type[Group1] = "ONE_LEVEL",
              symbols[Group1] = [ Super_L ],
              actions[Group1] = [
                      SetMods(modifiers=none),
                      SetMods(modifiers=Lock,clearLocks)
                      ]};

modifier_map Mod4 { <LCTL> };
```

However, the following simple remapping does work:

```
key <LCTL> {  type = "ONE_LEVEL", [ Super_L ] };

modifier_map Mod4 { <LCTL> };
```

What am I missing?

Comment: maybe this helps: https://askubuntu.com/questions/325272/permanent-xmodmap-in-ubuntu-13-04/347382#347382