# Turn off Caps Lock when a modifier key - other than Shift - is pressed

Tags: x11, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-layout, xkb

As an user of Emacs, which makes heavy use of modifier key plus letter combinations for commands, I sometimes forget to turn off Caps Lock before issuing a command, leading to unpredictable results.

Apparently, this can be accomplished [via XKB](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/65641/8785), but I couldn't make it work.

Comment: I don't think it's possible to do that without a lot of effort. Why not get rid of CapsLock altogether? The rare times it's useful, you can type lowercase then use C-x C-u.

Comment: I would rather keep Caps Lock, as I use Visual Studio, too.